SSIS expression: convert date to DDMMYYYY
I'd like some help editing the current date.  I need getdate -1 day, but the entry must look like DDMMYYYY.
RIGHT( "00"+ (DT_WSTR, 2) (DAY(GETDATE())-1),2)+RIGHT( "00"+ (DT_WSTR, 2)
MONTH(GETDATE()),2)+(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(GETDATE())
Unfortunately, the first day of the month gives the wrong date.
Today is 01/07/2024 and I need the date 30/06/2024(30062024)
Thank you all,
John
RIGHT( "00"+ (DT_WSTR, 2) (DAY(GETDATE())-1),2)+RIGHT( "00"+ (DT_WSTR, 2)
MONTH(GETDATE()),2)+(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(GETDATE())

An easier approach would be to just use the CONVERT() function with the right format mask:
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 103), '/', '');
-- 30062024 (query run on 1st July, 2024)

The format mask 103 will convert yesterday's date to DD/MM/YYYY.  We then remove the forward slash separators since you don't want them there.

thank you, but I would need in SSIS
